# svk checksum mismatch

Tags: version-control, svk

I've been using SVK without any issues the last 6 months. I then attempted to commit a file, when the following error occurred:

```
%> svk commit -m "Message" foo/bar/file.txt
Commit into mirrored path: merging back directly.
Merging back to mirror source file:///usr/local/svn/repo.
A checksum mismatch occurred: Base checksum mismatch on '/trunk/foo/bar/file.txt':
   expected:  9e421f7db5c4c0d6796c90524456d7f4
     actual:  ed4e76ccf3e54223908179735ecf1e89
```

Anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just needed **svk up -s**, answer found here:

[Working with SVK in a multi-user environment](http://kbase.wincent.com/old/knowledge-base/Working_with_SVK_in_a_multi-user_environment.html)

> ... svk up is
>   not enough to ensure that your depot
>   reflects the latest changes in the
>   remote repository. Instead you must
>   perform an svk sync (see svk help sync
>   for information about options) to
>   bring the local depot up to date, or
>   pass the -s switch to svk up to
>   achieve the same effect ...

```
# alternative 1:
svk sync //mirrors/mirrored_repo_name
svk up

# alternative 2:
svk up -s
```